# I want to know stochastic derivation of zero coupon bond formula

Tags: stochastic-calculus

[image]

I'm elementary level of stochastic calculus.
In the above picture, from equation (11) to (12) I don't know what is the clue of $μ(t)$ is the expectation of $r(t)$ and how from this identity we can get equation (12)

Also, I totally don't know how to derive equation (13).

I have a reference book that shreve's stochastic calculus for finance.
And I want to know where page I need to refer to understand this derivation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that $E[r(t)] = \mu(t)$ because the expectation (under some assumption, true in this case) of a stochastic integral is zero.

You get (12) by simple algebra (try writing r(s) and r(t) separately...).

This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972254/expectation-of-stochastic-integral-martingale

Regarding (13), I would advise to search "Quadratic variation" and "distribution of stochastic integral"...